# How to check the previous value of a field from the OnValidate event handler?

Tags: validation, delphi, dataset, delphi-2007, tfield

I need to validate the new value of a `TField` based on the previos value of the field itself.

e.g: the field's value can only be changed to bigger values

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
  if(???) then
    raise Exception.Create('The new value is not bigger than the previous one');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dst : TClientDataSet;
  Fld : TIntegerField;
begin
  //dataset
  Dst := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  Dst.FieldDefs.Add('TEST', ftInteger, 0);
  Dst.CreateDataSet();
  Dst.Active := True;
  Fld := Dst.Fields[0] as TIntegerField;
  Dst.Append();
  Fld.AsInteger := 5;
  Dst.Post();
  Fld.OnValidate := FldOnValidate;


  //this should be ok (from 5 to 6)
  Dst.Edit;
  Fld.AsInteger := 6;
  Dst.Post;

  //this should not pass the validation (from 6 to 5)
  Dst.Edit;
  Fld.AsInteger := 5;
end;
```

I've tried to check the `OldValue`, `NewValue`, `AsVariant` and `Value` properties but I always get the new value:

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
  ShowMessage(
    'OldValue = ' + VarToStr(AField.OldValue) + sLineBreak +
    'NewValue = ' + VarToStr(AField.NewValue) + sLineBreak +
    'AsVariant = ' + VarToStr(AField.AsVariant) + sLineBreak +
    'Value = ' + VarToStr(AField.Value)
  );
end;
```

Hope someone could enlighten me about that

Comment: The data you are looking for is simply not available in the `OnValidate` event.  The only thing the `OnValidate` event is good for is raising an exception if the new value is to be rejected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm beginning to think so... May I ask you how you think the behavior described in the question should be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Unassigned`

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
    if Sender.OldValue <> Unassigned then
      if Sender.NewValue <= Sender.OldValue then
        raise Exception.Create('The new value is not bigger than the previous one');
end;
```

But the right place is `OnChange` event

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1ValChange(Sender: TField);

begin
    if Sender.OldValue <> Unassigned then
      if Sender.NewValue <= Sender.OldValue then
        raise Exception.Create('The new value is not bigger than the previous one');
end;
```

Comment: in my `FldOnValidate`, `Sender.NewValue` is always equal to `Sender.OldValue`

Comment: I see you posted a similar comment on my answer, which I have since deleted.  did you actually try my code?

Comment: @MartynA Weird, I think I have D7 I'll install it and see.